# Function moddatetime() does not exist posgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

**my docker-compose:**

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: location
    ports: 
    - 5432:5432
```

**/db/users.sql - init dump**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TRIGGER users_moddatetime
  BEFORE UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE moddatetime (updated_at);

INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, phone, email) VALUES('Name', 'Lastname', '986754673823', 'test@mail.com');
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, phone, email) VALUES('Test', 'TEst', '9878721632163', 'test2@mail.com');
```

When I'm runing *docker-compose up* I have an error **function moddatetime() does
not exist**. Any ideas?

Comment: Which [chapter in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) made you believe there is such a function?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156980/create-a-trigger-on-all-the-last-modified-columns-in-postgresql/157096#157096

Comment: So did you install [that extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-spi.html#id-1.11.7.45.8)?

Comment: Add this: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS moddatetime;` at the top of /db/users.sql